# Good architecture for app with variable list of attributes

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

We are breaking a large asp.net web forms app into chunks and one of the pieces will be rebuilt using asp.net mvc. There are 2 primary types of orders (lets say types A and B). Each order has secondary types (lets say A1,A2, B1, B2, etc.) and each order has attributes.   Type A* orders share almost all of the attributes and Type B* orders share half of all the attributes. From the order history we found most of the orders placed were of Type A. The current design uses user controls for the order form for each secondary order type so there is user control for A1, another for A2, etc. The attributes are fields in these user controls.

As part of the redesign we wanted to see if we can get away from user controls and instead generate the order form with the necessary attributes dynamically while keeping the app lightweight and also be able to add a new secondary order type with minimal effort.

Design 1: Create a table with all possible attributes and map them to each secondary type and turn on/off attributes? It could get very granular and include information about how an attribute should be rendered.
Pros: Adding secondary order type is easy, just need to add mapping for new order type. 
Cons: Adding new attributes will requires changes to mapping table and perhaps all the layers. May need an admin section to manage mappings.

Design 2: Use jquery templates to replace user controls, send up json to the server.
Pros: Easy to add new form for a new secondary order type. 
Cons: some logic may have to go into the templates (views)

Any advice on which one of these is a good design? Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your database design has nothing to do with ASP.Net or JQuery. You need to worry about building a solid data model.

Table Inheritance and a good ORM will help here.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET